# Include remote web page into Servlet response

Tags: servlets, include

I need to have servlet exposed to the Internet that includes into its response remote web page with images! which hosted only in Intranet, there for in not accessible for outer clients. Is it possible to implement and how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using HttpURLConnection you write a redirect servlet which redirects the requests to remote server.

Create a ***HttpURLConnection*** to the remote pages, get the inputstream from the ***HttpURLConnection*** and write it to the client outputstream.

Comment: Will it download remote web page including images??

Comment: Using HttpURLConnection you can make a single request. You can write a redirect servlet which redirects the request the requests to remote server.

Comment: It will be server side redirect? Because client has no direct access to remote page which I need to show him. Thanks!

Comment: I have tried HttpURLConnection - it does not return images :(